# How to return all messages from array

Tags: ios, arrays, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

```
   NSArray *mystring = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    mystring = _fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects;
  // NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",mystring];

    _messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:mystring];

    for (Message *msg in _messages) {

        [mystring lastObject];
        NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",msg.text];




    self.messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:

                     [[JSQMessage alloc] initWithSenderId:kJSQDemoAvatarIdWoz
                                        senderDisplayName:_user_email
                                                     date:[NSDate distantPast]
                                                     text:text],




                     nil];
```

My array contain right now 3 messages for example and then on the app I only can see the last message from the array. I know the problem which is maybe I'm just assuming: or something wrong with my declaration of the array maybe **.first** object or **.last** object or **.count** needed to be set in some way Or most likely I'm missing something in the [JSQMESSAGE] object that will return all messages array into the app. Either way that's way I'm here for that, so if some one can guideline me on what to do, for sure I can't call the `[[JSQMESSAGE ALLOC]` a million time's...

I need some example with NSINTEGER or something I just need all messages to be displayed how can I do that? also How can I see all the sender messages not just the received messages?
And also in general some help with this un clear FrameWork will be great.

***I'm using core data with fetchedResultsController.*
*And JSQMessages framework.***

***The simulator Screen shot image:***

http://postimg.org/image/gkjpssbbd/

Comment: There are many things wrong with he code you posted. The code and what you say in your text indicate that you have a poor knowledge of iOS programing. You need to learn the basics before using advanced concepts like core data.

Comment: No sir its very simple and my knowledge is pretty good not the best but I know some few staff so let me disagree on you with that. Now that been said I just thought this is something simple I guess I'm wrong and it's more complex then I thought.

Comment: It is simple.  You're having trouble because you don't know what you're doing.  You can start by learning how to format your code.  (Come back and ask a new question when you clearly understand why the first two lines are bogus.)

Comment: There are at least three bugs in the above code, probably 4.  (Can't tell for sure since you've not shown us the declarations.)

Comment: Seem like you should learn some staff and come back. NSFetchresultcontroller can only work with no NSArray therefore You Can't assign message which are in NSMutable array (they have to be because JSQMessages framework demo showing that they have to be in the NSMutableArray form also in the JSQMessages docs). Since that I create my simple NSArray mystring to hold my '.fetchedobjects' array from NSFetchResultController and then I Initialise that array to my _messages NSMutableArray. I maybe bad at explaining my self in words in here but Im sure do know what i'm doing sir  so don't patronise me .

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly it looks like you're re-initializing your array with the objects of what appears to be another array. This would just add the JSQMessages array to your self.messages array as an object, with the object actually containing the messages. I don't know anything about JSQMessage but it seems that what it's returning to you is already an array of messages. Simply set your self.messages array equal to the JSQMessages array after initializing self.messages.

If this is not the case then actually read the documentation for that framework.

Comment: tried what you said and It still return to only one message